# jBPM REST API for Simulation

Tags: rest, jbpm

Does jBPM have a REST API to run simulations? If not, are there any plans to implement one? [I didn't find any reference to it in the documentation.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since simulation is typically used inside designer (including all the visual support) there is no eemote api for this.  You could use the jbpm-simulation (or expose that through a remite api even) but there are no concrete plans to do this at the moment.